# Mongo Query - Number of Constraints vs Speed (and Indexing!)

Tags: mongodb, indices

Lets say I have a million entries in the db with 10 fields/("columns") in the db. It seems to me that the more columns I search by, the faster the query goes - for example:

```
db.items.find( { 
    $and: [ 
        { field1: x }, 
        { field2: y },
        { field3: z}
    ] 
} )
```

is faster than:

```
db.items.find( { 
    $and: [ 
        { field1: x }, 
        { field2: y }
    ] 
} )
```

While I would love to say "Great, this makes total sense to me" - it doesn't. I just know it's happening in my particular case, and wondering if this is actually always true. If so, ideally, I would like to know why.

Furthermore, when creating multi-field indices, does it help to have them in any sort of order. For example, let's say I add a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/create-a-compound-index/#build-a-compound-index):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1 } )
```

Do these have any sort of order? If yes, would the order matter? Let's say 90% of items will match the field1 criteria, but 1% of items will match the field 3 criteria. Would ordering them make some sort of difference?

Answer (score 3):

It may be just the case that more restrictive query returns less documents, since *90% of items will match the field1 criteria* and only *1% of items will match the field 3 criteria*. Check what [explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) says for both queries.

Mongo has quite good [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/). Give it a try. Play with different indexes and different queries. Not on production db of course.

Order of fields in the index matters. If you have an index `{ field1: 1, field2: 1, field3: 1 }`
and a query `db.items.find( { field2: x, field3: y })`, the index wount be used at all,
and for query `db.items.find( { field1: x, field3: y })` it can be used only partially for `field1`.

From the other hand, order of conditions in the query does not matter:
`db.items.find( { field1: x, field2: y })` is as good as
`db.items.find( { field2: y, field1: x })` and will use the index in both cases.

Choosing indexing strategy you should examine both **data and typical queries**. It may be the case, that [index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-intersection/) works better for you, and instead of a single compound index you get better total performance with simple indexes like `{ field1: 1}`, `{ field2: 1}`, `{ field3: 1}`, rather than multiple compound indexes for different kind of queries.

It is also important to check index size to [fit it in memory](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/ensure-indexes-fit-ram/#indexing-right-handed). In most cases anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated... MongoDB keeps recently accessed documents in RAM, and the query plan is calculated the first time a query is executed, so the second time you run a query may be much faster than the first time.

But, putting that aside, the order of a compound index does matter. In a compound index, you can use the index in the order it was created, a bit like opening a door, walking through and finding that you have more doors to open.

So, having two overlapping indexes setup, e.g.:

```
{ city: 1, building: 1, room: 1 }
```

AND

```
{ city: 1, building: 1 }
```

Would be a waste, because you can still search for all the rooms in a particular building using the first two levels (fields) of the "{ city: 1, building: 1, room: 1 }" index.

Your intuition does make sense. If you had to find a particular room in a building, going straight to the right city, straight to the right building and then knowing the approximate place in the building will make it faster to find the room than if you didn't know the approximate place (assuming that there are lots of rooms). Take a look at levels in a B-Tree, e.g. the search visualisation here: http://visualgo.net/bst.html

It's not universally the case though, not all data is neatly distributed in a sort order - for example, English names or words tend to clump together under common letters - there's not many words that start with the letter X.

The (free, online) MongoDB University developer courses cover indexes quite well, but the best way to find out about the performance of a query is to look at the results of the explain() method against your query to see if an index was used, or whether a collection was scanned (COLLSCAN).

```
db.items.find( { 
    $and: [ 
        { field1: x }, 
        { field2: y }
    ] 
})
.explain()
```